# How can I search pipeline with another pipeline value on google cloud dataflow

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-dataflow

I would like to search text which includes specified word from stream data with google cloud dataflow.

In detail, I will deal with following two stream.

- stream A: element of stream is "word"
- stream B: element of stream is "text". and each text consists of "word". This text may have "word" on stream A

Many "text" flow into stream B frequently. On the other hand, "word" flow into stream A occasionally.

When "word" flow into stream A, I would like to search "text" which has "word" and flow into stream B after 5 minutes ago.

Example

```
time  stream A : stream B
00:01 -          this is an apple
00:02 -          this is an orange
00:03 -          I have an apple
00:04 apple                        <= "this is an apple" and "I have an apple" are found
00:05 this                         <= "this is an apple" and "this is an orange" are found
```

Can I search text with google cloud dataflow?

Comment: Is there an expiration time for the match, after which you won't continue looking?

Comment: I would like to check each time "word" flow into stream A. so, I would like to continue to check until I explicitly stop job .

Comment: Is there a bound on the overall size of stream A?  Are you looking for all matches or one per element?

Comment: I mean "one per element". If a "word" flows into stream A, I would like to find "text" which has this "word" only one time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, there are multiple ways to achieve something like what you want. I will describe two variations.

The basic idea in my example code is to use an inner join and `SlidingWindows` of five minutes. You can implement the join using `ParDo` side inputs or `CoGroupByKey`, depending on your data sizes.

Here is how you set up your inputs and windowing:

```java
PCollection<String> streamA = ...; 
PCollection<String> streamB = ...;

PCollection<String> windowedStreamA = streamA.apply(
    Window.into(
        SlidingWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(5)).every(...)));

PCollection<String> windowedStreamB = streamB.apply(
    Window.into(
        SlidingWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(5)).every(...)));
```

You may want to adjust the size of windows or period to meet your specification & performance needs.

Here is a sketch of how to do the join with side inputs. This will iterate over the entire five minute window of `streamB` for each element of `streamA`, so performance will suffer if windows get large.

```java
PCollectionView<Iterable<String>> streamBview = streamB.apply(View.asIterable());

PCollection<String> matches = windowedStreamA.apply(
    ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, String>() {
      @Override void processElement(ProcessContext context) {
        for (String text : context.sideInput()) {
          if (split(text).contains(context.element())) {
            context.output(text);
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

Here is a sketch of how to do this with `CoGroupByKey` by pre-splitting the text and joining each keyword with the lines that contain that keyword. There is similar logic in the `TfIdf` example included with the SDK.

```java
PCollection<KV<String, Void>> keyedStreamA = windowedStreamA.apply(
    MapElements
        .via(word -> KV.of(word, null))
        .withOutputType(new TypeDescriptor<KV<String, Void>>() {}));

PCollection<KV<String, String>> keyedStreamB = windowedStreamB.apply(
    FlatMapElements
        .via(text -> split(text).forEach(word --> KV.of(word, text))
        .withOutputType(new TypeDescriptor<KV<String, String>>() {}));


TupleTag<Void> tagA = new TupleTag<Void>() {};
TupleTag<String> tagB = new TupleTag<String>() {};

KeyedPCollectionTuple coGbkInput = KeyedPCollectionTuple
    .of(tagA, keyedStreamA)
    .and(tagB, keyedStreamB);

PCollection<String> matches = coGbkInput
    .apply(CoGroupByKey.create())
    .apply(FlatMapElements
        .via(result -> result.getAll(tagB))
        .withOutputType(new TypeDescriptor<String>()));
```

The best approach will depend on your data. If you are OK with getting more matches than just the last five minutes you can tune the amount of data duplication in windows by enlarging your sliding windows and having a larger period. You can also use triggers to tune when output is produced.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Your answer is that I was looking for. Thank you!!